# client certificate not sent by postman

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, postman

Can anyone shet some light on how I can debug the matching of certificates configured in Postman?

**Problem:**
I’m trying to connect to a REST service using a SSL client certificate. I configured it in the settings tab the same way as in  [set-and-view-ssl-certificates-with-postman](http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/12/05/set-and-view-ssl-certificates-with-postman/)

When checking the console I don’t see the certificate being sent and get failure:c:\projects\electron\vendor\node\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:1494:SSL alert number 40

**Context:**

Postman v 6.4.2 running on windows 10

(for security reasons some information below replaced by dummy info)

Using the same certificate/key/password I can setup a connection using openssl. (checked for validity of certificates, TSL v1.1 and v1.2 supported, no SNI issues)
The server certificate is signed by a trusted CA (I tested with both --SSL certificate verification-- on and off )
In the Postman console I dont see the certifciate being sent.

---- [console output] ----

GET https://somehost:443/somepath?someparameter=9076443&somedate=2017-02-17T00:00:00.000

```
Error: write EPROTO 101057795:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:c:\projects\electron\vendor\node\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:1494:SSL alert number 40 101057795:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:c:\projects\electron\vendor\node\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:659:



    Request Headers:
        appid:“42”
        cache-control:“no-cache”
        ipaddress:“192.68.1.1”
        postman-token:“some-token”
        role:“Applicatie”
        userid:“6x9”
```

---- [end console output] ----

[image of certificate configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Gfma.png)

I matched, matched and rematched the hostname

A search on the interweb did not learn me anything I did not try yet…

**Questions**

```
Is there any debug option that will show the way the certificates are matched
is there any way I can force postman to pick a configured certificate
any other ideas on how to proceed on this problem
```

any help appreciated

**Additional info**

Monitoring with wireshark shows no certificate is sent.
(Postman console did not show a certificate being sent. I assume from examples that it will log which certificates it will/does send for a given request)

[snippet wireshark output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqRMK.png)

**Postman app in chrome**
it does work from chrome, using the chrome keystore
Using the pk12 form of the same key (original postman request uses the .cer form) imported into the chrome keystore, the requests work.

**Chrome app will not do**

Obvious question is: “why not keep using the chrome app”
because its depricated and we use the newer 6.x test functions not supported in version 5.x

Question posted on Postman help forum with no answer about a week ago:
[OP on postman helpforum](https://community.getpostman.com/t/ssl-certificate-matching-does-not-seem-to-work/2974)

**Additional additional info**

It works on newman

Comment: Old question, but I have the same problem (Postman 7.25.0).  Postman sends a configured client certificate fine for one of our test environment URLs, but not for another.  I have triple-checked and re-added the certificate a number of times, using both crt+key and pfx+passphrase methods.  My own software sent the client cert correctly with both URLs.  Eventually tried instead with Insomnia and everything was fine, so can't think of anything else except a bug in Postman.

Answer (score 2):

If you can download postman app then there is an option under preference/certificate and under there is an option 'Client Certificate'.

You need to provide both .cert and .key file into respective section, provide host name and key password if any. Click "save". next time you send a request matching hostname , postman app will send the certificate along with the way. You can validate in console output.

Comment: You can use an `*` (asterisk) in the `Host` setting (`*.adp.com`) to match subdomains like `accounts.adp.com` and `api.adp.com`.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue when I typed path to CRT and KEY files instead of using file dialog.
Just click Choose File button instead of pasting file path when adding certificate.